# BUILD FAILED in 2s [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.[cordova.cmd compile android exited with exit code 1]

Tags: angular, windows, visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

Can I fix this problem?

[image: build failed with an exception]⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: please paste code instead of image

Answer (score 0):

You are missing android build tools,

```
android update sdk -u -a -t <package no.>
```

package no is the version of build tools you want to install, in your case it is 
19.1.0 or higher.